# Getting File not found error after calling GetCursorInfo

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I am trying to get global cursor info using `GetCursorInfo()` using pinvoke. However, when I test it with the cursor on any application, I get

> error 2 (File not found)

after calling `GetLastError()`.

Here is my code

```
CursorInfo info = new CursorInfo();
bool success = GetCursorInfo(ref info);
Console.WriteLine(success);
if (success)
{
  Console.WriteLine("here");
  return GetSelectionText(info.Handle);
}
Console.WriteLine(GetLastError());
return "";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show your pinvoke declaration

Comment: @stuartd I actually just realized I wasn't setting the size `info.Size = Marshal.SizeOf(info.GetType());` It works now. My pinvoke is ```[DllImport("user32.dll")]public static extern bool GetCursorInfo(out CursorInfo info);```

Comment: Now I am getting error 1400. Invalid window handle

Comment: Can you show your CursorInfo struct? Also noting that the [PInvoke page for GetCursorInfo](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getcursorinfo) passes the value by `ref` rather than as `out`

Comment: ```[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct CursorInfo
        {
            public int Size;
            public int Flags;
            public IntPtr Handle;
            public Point Position;
        }```

Comment: Using GetLastError() is quite wrong.  The only guarantee you have to get a correct value is by setting the SetLastError property of the [DllImport] attribute to true.  And using Marshal.GetLastError() or throwing a Win32Exception right away (better).  That way there can't be any other code that might run and alter the last error state, like the just-in-time compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I realized the Handle property gets the "kind" of cursor. Therefore to get the actual window on which the global cursor is at, I passed `CursorInfo`'s position to `WindowFromPoint`.